# Cannot get UDP hole punching right. Error: recvfrom: connection refused

Tags: sockets, go, networking, udp

I am trying to connect two peers behind same NAT using [UDP hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) but whenever 1 client send UDP packet to other client, it receives error:

```
read udp4 192.168.0.xx:xx->192.168.0.xx:xx: recvfrom: connection refused
```

I followed implementation from [here](https://bford.info/pub/net/p2pnat/).

Some background about my code:

**server.go**

1. init UDP server
2. start listening for packets on given IP:PORT (user input)
3. a. receive packet of type ***new_connection*** for new client (does not exist already), store client_name, IP:PORT mapping in a variable and send ***connection_success*** in response.

   b. receive packet of type ***connection_request*** from client A requesting from B's details, send ***mapping_response*** packet to client A with B's details and send client B ***peer_request*** packet with A's details.

code for server.go:

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "os"
)

var mapping map[string]*net.UDPAddr

func initServer(addr string) (*net.UDPConn, error) {
    s, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4", addr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }
    c, err := net.ListenUDP("udp4", s)
    return c, nil
}

func main() {
    port := ":" + os.Args[1]
    mapping = make(map[string]*net.UDPAddr)
    c, err := initServer(port)
    defer c.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    listen(c)
}

func listen(c *net.UDPConn) {
    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        n, addr, err := c.ReadFromUDP(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        } else  {
            s := strings.Split(string(buffer[0:n]), " ")
            packetType, packetData := s[0], s[1]
            go handle(c, packetType, packetData, addr)
        }
    }
}

func addMapping(c *net.UDPConn, data string, addr *net.UDPAddr) {
    if _, ok := mapping[data]; !ok {
        mapping[data] = addr
        fmt.Println(mapping)
        data := generateData("connection_success", "hello")
        sendResponse(c, data, addr)
    }
}

func makeConnection(c *net.UDPConn, name string, addr1 *net.UDPAddr) {
    addr2 := getAddress(name)
    var data string
    data = generateData("mapping_response", addr2.String())
    sendResponse(c, data, addr1)
    data = generateData("peer_request", addr1.String())
    sendResponse(c, data, addr2)
}

func handle(c *net.UDPConn, packetType string, packetData string, addr *net.UDPAddr) {
    switch packetType {
    case "new_connection":
        addMapping(c, packetData, addr)
    case "connection_request":
        makeConnection(c, packetData, addr)
    default:
        break
    }
}

func getAddress(name string) *net.UDPAddr {
    return mapping[name]
}

func generateData(packetType string, packetData string) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", packetType, packetData)
}

func sendResponse(c *net.UDPConn, data string, addr *net.UDPAddr) {
    fmt.Println(data, addr)
    _, err := c.WriteToUDP([]byte(data), addr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
}
```

**client.go**

1. init UDP client for server
2. get client_name as input (user input)
3. send packet of type ***new_connection*** to server every 10s.
4. a. receive packet of type ***connection_success***, ask user whom to connect with (client B) and send ***connection_request*** packet to server asking B's details.

   b. receive packet of type ***mapping_response***, try to connect to client B by using sending ***establish_connection*** packet to client B every 3s.

   c. receive packet of type ***peer_request***, try same thing as 3b from client B side.

code for client.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "net"
    "time"
    "strings"
)

func initClient(addr string) (*net.UDPConn, error) {
    s, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4", addr)
    c, err := net.DialUDP("udp4", nil, s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }
    return c, nil
}

func main() {
    serverAddress := os.Args[1]
    c, err := initClient(serverAddress)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer c.Close()
    name := getInput()
    go addMappingToServer(c, name)
    listen(c)
}

func addMappingToServer(c *net.UDPConn, name string) {
    for {
        data := generateData("new_connection", name)
        sendPacket(c, data)
        time.Sleep(10*time.Second)
    }
}

func listen(c *net.UDPConn) {
    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        n, addr, err := c.ReadFromUDP(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        } else  {
            s := strings.Split(string(buffer[0:n]), " ")
            packetType, packetData := s[0], s[1]
            go handle(c, packetType, packetData, addr)
        }
    }
}

func handle(c *net.UDPConn, packetType string, packetData string, addr *net.UDPAddr) {
    fmt.Println(packetType, packetData)
    switch packetType {
    case "connection_success":
        getPeerMapping(c)
    case "peer_request":
        establishConnectionToPeer(packetData)
    case "mapping_response":
        establishConnectionToPeer(packetData)
    default:
        break
    }
}

func generateData(packetType string, packetData string) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", packetType, packetData)
}

func sendPacket(c *net.UDPConn, data string) {
    _, err := c.Write([]byte(data))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
}

func sendPacketToAddr(c *net.UDPConn, data string, addr *net.UDPAddr) {
    _, err := c.WriteToUDP([]byte(data), addr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
}

func getInput() string {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print(">> ")
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    return text[0:len(text)-1]
}

func getPeerMapping(c *net.UDPConn) {
    peer := getInput()
    data := generateData("connection_request", peer)
    sendPacket(c, data)
}

func establishConnectionToPeer(peerAddr string) {
    c, err := initClient(peerAddr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer c.Close()
    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        data := generateData("establish_connection", "hello")
        sendPacket(c, data)
        n, addr, err := c.ReadFromUDP(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        } else {
            fmt.Println("packet recieved from peer data : %s, addr : %#v", string(buffer[0:n]), addr)
            break
        }
        time.Sleep(3*time.Second)
    }

}
```

The problem that I am facing is in line

```
n, addr, err := c.ReadFromUDP(buffer)
```

inside *establishConnectionToPeer* function and I am getting error I mentioned above (**connection refused**).

**Scenario**

Client A and server are on 1 host and client B on another. Both hosts are behind same NAT.

**Sample output:**

*for server:*

```
map[abc:192.168.0.78:45999 xyz:192.168.0.10:44207]
```

meaning client abc's IP:PORT is *192.168.0.78:45999* and for xyz, it is *192.168.0.10:44207*

*for client abc:*

```
read udp4 192.168.0.78:40934->192.168.0.10:44207: recvfrom: connection refused
```

*for client xyz:*

```
read udp4 192.168.0.10:49708->192.168.0.78:45999: recvfrom: connection refused
```

Problem is clear: both clients opened another port (different from what they opened to communicate from server)

What is wrong with the client code above, and what can I do to resolve it? It would be great if someone can provide (or modify above) code piece to make it start working.

I assume it's not the case that my router does not support UDP hole punching because I can use skype using it (and I read from [here](http://www.h-online.com/security/features/How-Skype-Co-get-round-firewalls-747197.html) that skype uses hole punching).